# ssh correct syntax to login GCP ubuntu instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh

I have google account that is not @gmail ; it is "XXXX@myUnuiversity.edu"

I created ubuntu instance in Google Cloud Platform

I want to use mobaXterm to connect to this instance:

I used:

ssh XXXX@myUnuiversity.edu@the_external_IP_for_the_insatnce

But, I got error

Permission denied (publickey).

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur for several reasons. The following are some of the most common causes of this error:

**1.- You used an SSH key stored in metadata to connect to a VM that has OS Login enabled.** If OS Login is enabled on your project, your VM doesn't accept SSH keys that are stored in metadata.

To resolve this issue, try one of the following:

- [Connect to your VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance) using the Google Cloud Console or the gcloud command-line tool.
- [Add your SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#add_oslogin_keys) to OS Login.
- [Disable OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#enable_oslogin)

**2.- You used an SSH key stored in an OS Login profile to connect to a VM that doesn't have OS Login enabled.** If you disable OS Login, your VM doesn't accept SSH keys that were stored in your OS Login profile.

To resolve this issue, try one of the following:

- Connect to your VM using the Google Cloud Console or the gcloud command-line tool.  .
- [Enable OS Login.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#enable_oslogin)
- [Add your SSH keys to metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#edit-ssh-metadata)

**3.- You connected using a third-party tool and your SSH command is misconfigured.** If you connect using the ssh command but don't specify a path to your private key or you specify an incorrect path to your private key, your VM refuses your connection.

To resolve this issue, try one of the following:

Run the following command:

`ssh -i PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY USERNAME@EXTERNAL_IP`

Replace the following:

**PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY:** the path to your private SSH key file.

**USERNAME:** the username of the user connecting to the instance. If you manage your SSH keys in metadata, the username is what you specified when you created the SSH key. For OS Login accounts, the username is defined in your Google profile.

**EXTERNAL_IP:** The external IP address for your VM.

Here you can find the documentation from Google. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh

Answer (score 0):

> This error can occur for several reasons

More details/solutions in the link below:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#permission_denied

---

But the easiest way to connect via SSH client using the command-line, is to use `gcloud` using

```
gcloud compute ssh <YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME>
```

Below the doc explaining how to install `gcloud` (Google Cloud SDK)  on windows

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#windows